# PST Time conversion

Tags: java

Am calculating last business day of month the consolidation is like following -

•   AI.VOUCHER_DT >= 5:00 PM PST on the LAST business day of the month

•   AI.VOUCHER_DT <= 11:59:59 PM PST on the LAST calendar day of the month

•   Current system date / time < 3rd business day of the FOLLOWING month

For example, Feb 28(Sat) is the last calendar day of the month,the timing accrual file should include the vouchers that are created between 5:00 PM Feb 27(Fri) and 23:59:59 PM Feb 28(Sat).  The records would remain on the accrual until March 4th, which is the 3rd business day of the month in this example.

How i can compare this.

Comment: "How i can compare this" - Compare what? `AI.VOUCHER_DT`? Is it a string, a DateTime ... Are we talking Java 8?

Comment: AI.VOUCHER_DT  is a object and it will return a Date .

Comment: If in Java 8, I suggest using LocalDate from java.time namespace in favor of java.util.Date.

Comment: You need to write 3 methods.  The first method gets the Date of the last business day of the month at 5 pm.  The second method gets the Date of the last day of the month at 11:59:59 pm.  This is the easiest method to write.  The third method gets the Date of the 3rd business day of the month at midnight.  You didn't give a time component for this Date.  You can use the Calendar class to perform the calculations and return a Date object from each of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiscal date class that generates the 3 fiscal dates that you asked for.

I ran two tests, one for February 2015 and one for August 2016.  Here are the results of the test.

```
Fri, 27 Feb 2015 17:00:00 PST
Sat, 28 Feb 2015 23:59:59 PST
Wed, 04 Mar 2015 00:00:00 PST

Wed, 31 Aug 2016 17:00:00 PDT
Wed, 31 Aug 2016 23:59:59 PDT
Mon, 05 Sep 2016 00:00:00 PDT
```

The first date is the last business day of the month, the second date is the last day of the month, and the third date is the third business day of the following month.

Here's the code.  I used the Calendar class to do the date calculations.  The input month is zero based.  0 = January, 1 = February, etc.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class FiscalDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        sdf.setTimeZone(getTimeZone());

        displayDates(sdf, 2015, 1);
        displayDates(sdf, 2016, 7);
    }

    private static void displayDates(SimpleDateFormat sdf, int year, int month) {
        Date date = calculateLastBusinessDay(year, month);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
        date = calculateLastDay(year, month);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
        date = calculateThirdBusinessDay(year, month);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static Date calculateLastBusinessDay(int year, int month) {
        Calendar calendar = calculateLastCalendarDay(year, month);

        while (!isWeekday(calendar)) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    public static Date calculateLastDay(int year, int month) {
        Calendar calendar = calculateLastCalendarDay(year, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    public static Date calculateThirdBusinessDay(int year, int month) {
        Calendar calendar = calculateLastCalendarDay(year, month);
        int weekdayCount = 0;

        while (weekdayCount < 3) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            weekdayCount += isWeekday(calendar) ? 1 : 0;
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    private static Calendar calculateLastCalendarDay(int year, int month) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(getTimeZone());
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        return calendar;
    }

    private static boolean isWeekday(Calendar calendar) {
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return (dayOfWeek == Calendar.MONDAY)
                || (dayOfWeek == Calendar.TUESDAY)
                || (dayOfWeek == Calendar.WEDNESDAY)
                || (dayOfWeek == Calendar.THURSDAY)
                || (dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY);
    }

    private static TimeZone getTimeZone() {
        return TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    }

}
```

If you're in a different location than the United States, you would use a different time zone.